# Se puede modificar una clase desde otra en CSS?

Tags: html, css, web, diseño, style

Mi intención es tener dos párrafos dentro de una caja , entre ellos uno oculto y cuando pase el mouse por arriba de la caja , el que está oculto aparezca, miren este ejemplo en esta porción de código.

*HTLM*

```
<body>
    <div class="caja">
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, enim.<>
      </p>
      <p class="oculto">Esto debe de aparecer con el hover</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

*CSS*

```
.caja {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
    .oculto{
display:none}

.caja:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 500px;
}
```

Lo que yo quiero es que cuando se active el hover de la clase .caja, se muestre el párrafo oculto con clase .oculto , **Nota, no quiero que se muestre haciendole hover al parrafo oculto, "que tampoco se si se podría" ,lo que quiero que se muestre al hacerle hover a la clase .caja**

Comment: Trata de esta forma para dar el display block: `.caja:hover .oculto `

Comment: Lo que te recomiendo se llama selector de descendientes y aplica en este caso por que el elemento que quieres mostrar esta dentro de la etiqueta con la clase caja: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues todo correcto, solo faltaria sobrecargar tu hover con la clase oculta a mostrar, pasandola de  display none a block.

```css
.caja {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
    .oculto{
display:none}

.caja:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 500px;
  
}

.caja:hover .oculto{
    display:block;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="caja">
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, enim.<>
      </p>
      <p class="oculto">Esto debe de aparecer con el hover</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funcionaron perfectamente ambos comentarios

Answer (score 1):

Mientras lo oculto esté después del elemento que sirve para activarlo, se puede.

Una opción es la que ya se ve en la respuesta de @Felipe Urcia, pero tienes más:

### Si son elementos contiguos (o sea, uno está tras el otro)

```css
.interruptor {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.interruptor + .oculto {
        position: absolute;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
}

.interruptor:hover + .oculto {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;

}
```

```html
<p class="interruptor">Este párrafo sirve de interruptor para mostrar u ocultar el párrafo que viene a continuación</p>

<p class="oculto">Este párrafo está oculto hasta que se pasa el ratón por encima del párrafo «interruptor». Eso quiere decir que en dispositivos de pantalla táctil no se verá nunca :(</p>
```

### Si hay otros elementos entre los dos

```css
div {
    position: relative;
}

.interruptor {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.interruptor ~ .oculto {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.interruptor:hover ~ .oculto {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;

}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="interruptor">Este párrafo sirve de interruptor para mostrar u ocultar el párrafo que hay al final.</p>

    <p>Este párrafo está para poner algo entre los dos párrafos.</p>

    <ul>
        <li>también podría poner otros elementos</li>
        <li>como una lista</li>
        <li>o cualquier otro tipo de contenido</li>
    </ul>

    <p class="oculto">Este párrafo está oculto hasta que se pasa el ratón por encima del párrafo «interruptor». Eso quiere decir que en dispositivos de pantalla táctil no se verá nunca :(</p>
</div>
```

Se trata tan solo de encontrar el selector apropiado ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias me funcionaron perfectamente ambos comentarios